# Finding the angle made by a line in mathematical coordinates?

Tags: java, graphics

I have two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) in mathematical coordinates(bottom-left is origin). I have a scale factor `SCALE` to scale these coordinates to my screen coordinates and then Complementing the height to get the Original Screen coordinate(top-left is origin). I want to know the angle made by the 2 points in screen coordinate system. Currently i am doing the following:

```
theta=Math.atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
if(theta<0)
theta+=Math.PI;
```

But it is not working. Can i do this without scaling the coordinates?

EDIT: Sample Output for
x1= 7.2
y1= 9.575
x2= 5.4
y2= 7.15

is 53.414 degree.

Comment: Scaling the coordinates will not change the angle. Are you reading the value in Radians or in Degrees? It may be working, you just think it's not.

It would be great to know what you're getting on what inputs, because your equations look right.

Comment: Are the coordinates `int`s?

Comment: Angles are in Radian, Coordinates are float values.

Comment: 53 degrees looks about right. What value did you expect?

Comment: On screen co ordinates, assuming theta is measured +ve counter clockwise and x1,y1 is the pivot i expected 233.414 degree.

Comment: @Madeyedexter check my new answer that is what the code is getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation should work for you.

```
    float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y_2 - y_1, x_2 - x_1));

    //Take this out if you want negative values.
    if(angle < 0){
        angle += 360;
    }
```

This will return a value between 0 and 359. If you want negative values just take out the if statement.

You say it doesn't work. Do you mean to tell me that my eyes are lying to me?
[image]

Based on your above comment that you are expecting 233.41467. You should leave in the `angle += 360`

Comment: I think it should be `Math.atan2(y_2-y_1, x_2-x_1)` (first y, then x)

Comment: @Madeyedexter instead of using your pivot just use x1, x2, y1, y2.

Comment: @Madeyedexter you should cast to float also.

Comment: @ExcelledProducts: I flipped the negation in numerator and denominator and now it is working! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard equation for calculating the angle between two vectors of R^2 is the following: (assuming that alpha is the angle between the two vectors, v1 and v2 are the two vectors)

```
cos(alpha) = abs(dot(v1, v2)) / (norm(v1) * norm(v2))
```

So after scaling the two vectors v1=(x1, y1)^t and v2=(x2, y2)^t to screen coordiantes, you should use the formula above to calculate alpha. (dot means the dotproduct between v1 and v2, and norm is the standard euclidean metric).

After that you obtain the angle in radians (for a conversion to degrees you can simply divide by 2*Pi and multiply by 360).